# Optimize table does not run right after table mutation

Tags: clickhouse

I'm updating a table with table mutations like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE T1 
UPDATE column1 = replaceAll('X', 'Y')
```

After that, I'm sending `optimize-final` command with `clickhouse-client` like this:

```sql
OPTIMIZE TABLE T1 FINAL

Ok.

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```

But it returns instantly(`0.002 sec.`) and I can see the rows are not updated yet.

After a couple of seconds(10-50) I run the `optimize-final` command again but this time it hangs until the table is optimized.

Is this the expected behavior of `optimize-final`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can see the rows are not updated yet.

`ALTER TABLE T1 UPDATE` -- asynchronous

You should check `select count() from system.mutations where not is_done;` that your mutation is done.

---

In next versions you can run mutations synchronously
`ALTER TABLE T1 UPDATE column1 = replaceAll('X', 'Y') SETTINGS 
mutations_sync = 2`

*mutations_sync, 0, "Wait for synchronous execution of ALTER TABLE UPDATE/DELETE queries (mutations). 0 - execute asynchronously. 1 - wait current server. 2 - wait all replicas if they exist.*

---

> OPTIMIZE TABLE T1 FINAL

OPTIMIZE -- `merge` has no relation to mutations.

---

> 0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.

In some cases `OPTIMIZE` could not start and returns immediately

Use optimize_throw_if_noop to find out a reason

```
set optimize_throw_if_noop = 1;
OPTIMIZE TABLE T1 FINAL;
```